# How to run the installer from an iso file using c# code

Tags: c#

I have created an iso image with the installation folder of an application. I want to intialize the execution of the application form a .net code. I have been using the following code to open the image as a drive given that file explorer is the default application for opening iso files, then read the drives to check if there exists the file i want to run.

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Users\tjdtud\Desktop\done\publish.iso");

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DriveInfo[] diLocalDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        try
        {
            foreach (DriveInfo diLogicalDrive in diLocalDrives)
            {
                if (File.Exists(diLogicalDrive.Name + "setup.exe"))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(diLogicalDrive.Name + "setup.exe");
                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(diLogicalDrive.Name + "\\setup.exe");
                    //MessageBox.Show("Logical Drive: " + diLogicalDrive.Name,
                    //                "Logical Drives",
                    //                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    //                MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This code failes to work if file explorer is not the default iso opening application. Besides i have a strong feeling that it is not even close to the right way of doing it. Will very much appreciate any form of help or pointers to help links. Thank you for reading

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602439/vb-net-mount-iso

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.NET DiscUtils](https://github.com/discutils/discutils) to extract the file as follows:

```
using (FileStream isoStream = File.Open(@"C:\temp\sample.iso"))
{
    CDReader cd = new CDReader(isoStream, true);
    Stream fileStream = cd.OpenFile(@"Folder\Hello.txt", FileMode.Open);
    // Use fileStream...
}
```

Extract the file to a temporary location and then execute it.